# Why does my code mysteriously remove inserted data?

Tags: meteor, insert, iron-router

My code `buyList.insert();`successfully inserts data, but somewhere along the way the data is mysteriously removed. In various points in the code, I print out to the browser console in an attempt to figure out why, and at what point the removing happens, but cant figure out where this happens.

Kindly help me figure out what I am doing wrong. 
Following is an image indicating the location and the buyList.insert() function setup.

/myApp
 
../client/main.js

[image: Where buyList insert]

Kindly take note to the `console.log()` function between line 1246 to 1250 in the code above.

This translates to the below in the browser console, indicating that the data was saved:
[image: console output in the browser]

The code between 1253 to 1256 redirects to the previewPost page after 1 second. Find below the helper for the previewPost.

/myApp 
../client/main.js

[image: redirects to previewPost page after 1 second]

Note the `console.log()` on 204, 205 and 207, which translates to the below in the browser:
[image: browser output]

This is an indication that the data has been removed!?

Kindly help me understand what is going on.

Comment: Are you subscribing to this data anywhere?

Comment: @MasterAM Thanks! I had subscribed for it but forgotten to publish the collection. Thanks alot for pointing me in the right direction. How do I give you credit?